# In c++ how can I set registry key remotely, (connect works fine but set doesn't work!) - in a console app?

Tags: c++, registry

I have been trying this for three nights!

I want to create and then set the value for a registry key in a remote machine. It already has the remote registry key service enabled. And the machine has the same credentials with the one I am using.

So far, RegConnectRegistry works fine, and RegCreateKeyEx works perfectly as well. Next step is RegSetValueEx which doesn't work in remote. But it works locally.

After running the following method, I have \\SOFTWARE\\MICROSOFT\\WindowsAPP path created in registry key in remote machine. But the value "TestDataRoot" is never being written.

By the way, there is no error returned. All the commands succeeded!

Please take a look at my code:

```
void foo()
{
    LPCWSTR machineName = L"\\\\men000";
    HKEY key_ = NULL;
    std::wstring name = L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\WindowsAPP";
    std::wstring name2 = L"\\TestDataRoot";
    bool readOnly = false;
    DWORD lastError = 0xfffff;
    DWORD error_;
    long err = ERROR_SUCCESS;

    if ((err = RegConnectRegistry(machineName, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, &key_)) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Error is 0x%x\n", err);
        return;
    }

    DWORD isNew;
    HKEY newFabricRemoteKey = NULL;
    error_ = RegCreateKeyEx(key_, name.c_str(), 0, NULL, REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, readOnly ? KEY_READ : KEY_ALL_ACCESS, NULL, &newFabricRemoteKey, &isNew);

    DWORD value = 0xfffff;

    error_ = RegSetValueEx(key_, name2.c_str(), 0, REG_DWORD_LITTLE_ENDIAN, (const BYTE *)&value, 10);
}
```

Comment: What's the return value of RegCreateKeyEx and RegSetValueEx?

Comment: Not sure if this works, but apparently the size of DWORD is not 10 bytes.

Comment: Did you mean to set a value on `newFabricRemoteKey` instead of `key_`?

Answer (score 0):

Fix this code

```
//...
std::wstring name2 = L"TestDataRoot";
//...
error_ = RegSetValueEx(newFabricRemoteKey, name2.c_str(), 0, REG_DWORD_LITTLE_ENDIAN, reinterpret_cast<const BYTE *>(&value), sizeof(DWORD));
```